# Should I put (,) (;) or (:) after saying Think() Where am I now? Nowhere

Tags: punctuation

Think() Where am I now? Nowhere.

Comment: What's the context? What are you actually trying to say? I can think of no punctuation that would result in that string of words making sense.

Answer (score 3):

This seems very stylistic. Although two choices are incorrect.

> Think, where am I?

Looks goofy to me. Almost as if someone is addressing someone named "Think"

> Think; where am I?

I believe the ideas are too different to be connected with a semi-colon.

> Think: Where am I?

Is technically correct; however, I would personally use:

> Think. Where am I? Nowhere.

I would do this not only because it separates the two thoughts completely, it also gives the reader that full mental pause after think - the same pause you take when you are thinking. I also prefer this as "Nowhere." is also it's own sentence. The two one-word sentences surrounding "Where am I?" make the poignant passage aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: What about: Think - where am I?

Comment: @JohnGo-Soco I also like this. Personally I would choose "Think. Where am I?" instead; however, "Think - Where am I?" sounds better than OP's original semi-colon, colon, and comma options.